# PHP set date range based on total hour

Tags: php, date

I need to show date range if total hours more than 24 hours.

Assume, date: 25-JUL-2019
Total hours = 35.

So what I want is the date will show:

```
25-JUL-2019 | 26-JUL-2019
```

Total hours is random, it can be lower or higher and my clue maybe use `for` loop?

How to do that on PHP?

Comment: How the total hours is 35?

Comment: It's randomly value, from variable

Comment: what do you want to show if it less than 24?

Comment: Only 25-JUL-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DateTime object and loop over the number of days to add, and for each day you're adding, append it to an array. The number of days to add will be `floor($total_hours/24)` (which is true because we add the first, current day before the loop).

After the loop, use `implode(" | ", $dates)` to make it a single string, and use `strtoupper()` to convert `Jun` to `JUN`.

Note that this will not work for negative values of `$total_hours`.

```php
$total_hours = 52;
$start_date = '25-JUL-2019';
$dates = [];

$date = new \DateTime($start_date);
$dates[] = $date->format('d-M-Y');
for ($i = 0; $i < floor($total_hours / 24); $i++) {
    $date->modify('+1 day');
    $dates[] = $date->format('d-M-Y');
}

echo strtoupper(implode(' | ', $dates));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/bHQRU

Comment: Hi... how about if `$total_hours` = 52. It should be `25-JUL-2019 | 26-JUL-2019 | 27-JUL-2019`

Comment: You never said anything about that before, but that can be accomplished as well. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @emix I'm curious, why did you edit to change doublequotes to singlequotes? It changes virtually nothing. The namespace of `DateTime` I suppose is fine, but if we're not using namespaces, then it doesn't matter either.

Comment: Hi @Qirel, I tried to using `td` column inside loop. But it show me wrong date range. Please refer to this link https://3v4l.org/i4khn

Comment: @Qirel it's a good practice to always use singlequotes: they are faster, and less error prone. Only use doublequotes when you have a reason to do so. I also used the global namespace so the author won't come back to ask why the DateTime class was not found in his current namespace. He may use them or not, I don't know. This way the code is much more versatile for future readers.

Comment: @emix That's rather opinionated though. The difference in performance is extremely marginal - if you want to optimize something, that's not really where you should focus your efforts. "Less error prone" is only if you introduce dollar-signs into the strings - of which there are *none* here. The namespace edit *can* be useful - but it depends on where its used, the edit with the quotes is a rather meaningless edit.

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Its because the first date (current date) is handled before the loop. https://3v4l.org/jAGP8

Comment: I have related question, could we do on chat?

Comment: What's the question? But sure, we could move it into a chat.

Comment: OK noted, I will invite you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196963/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-qirel).

Comment: Hi @Qirel kindly please have a look on chat

Comment: Hi @Qirel, please refer to this my related question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217699/php-customize-table-column-based-on-condition

Comment: Hi @Qirel I have new question still regarding this, please refer to this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263488/php-ignoring-background-colour-on-table-column-based-on-time-master-condition

Answer (score 0):

Simple function with no error handling that seems to be what you're after.

`getDateRange('25-JUL-2019', 35)` = `25-JUL-2019 | 26-JUL-2019`

`getDateRange('25-JUL-2019', 92)` = `25-JUL-2019 | 28-JUL-2019`

```
/**
 * @param string $start Start date in just about any reasonable format
 * @param int $hours Number of hours
 * @return string
 */
function getDateRange($start , $hours) {
    $start = is_numeric($start) ? $start : strtotime($start);

    if ($hours < 24) {
        return strtoupper(date("d-M-Y", $start));
    }

    $end = $start + ($hours * 3600);
    return strtoupper(date("d-M-Y", $start) . " | " . date("d-M-Y", $end));
}
```

Comment: Note this assumes that you want to start counting hours from the beginning of the provided day, but that can be changed easily if that's not the case.    (Instead of checking hours < 24, just check if the end date is different to the start and it will work from any time that is passed in)